# Is it able to adjust HEAP size IN APPLICATION on a STM32 microcontroller?

Tags: arm, size, heap-memory, stm32

In my program, I'm using a lot of malloc(), and it's targeting chips with different RAM sizes(same peripherals and footprint of course), so I want to set HEAP size **in my c code application**, before the first call to malloc().

Setting HEAP or STACK size in IDE before compile is not I wanted. I searched all around and found nothing.

So, is that possible?

Comment: if you are developping a bare-metal program I would strongly suggest to NOT use dynamic memory. There is a reason why everyone says that..

Comment: the heap size is usually hard coded in the assembly file where the vector table is defined. The heap size symbol is used by the C runtime code to initialise the libc (for example Newlib if you're using GCC)

Comment: I understand you want to modify the heap size in your main (ie. after the CRT has been called). Well it is probably possible but probably a very bad idea: you don't have virtual memory so the heap is just an area of RAM. if you increase it, you will overlap other data.

Comment: Most common heap implementations assume that there is infinite RAM. If you use one like this then then as long as your heap is the last thing in memory it will correctly grow upwards into however much memory you really have! However, it is also relatively common to have the stack in memory after the heap, so if you have this, then your real question becomes "How do I relocate stack to start at the top of memory". This is fairly easy if you are not using an RTOS, but the depends on your toolchain and detecting the amount of memory depends on the platform. Maybe edit the question with details.

Comment: If you use gnu arm toolchain then that info is used only to do static check during compilation. Afaik sbrk inside newlib provided by toolchain doesn't check ram boundaries. So you're free to go.

Comment: I use IAR, the HEAP size seem to have affect on malloc(), it returns zero when there is not enough memory left, the free memory must be calculated using the pre-defined HEAP size. I can set the HEAP size to maximum, and put HEAP at the last section of ram, and HEAP is growing upwards, but then malloc() will not indicate error when the allocated mamory is out of the physical boundary.